# '1 hours ago': part nine

Tags: bug, plurals

> **Note**: This post is not for the faint of heart. In this post, a pluralization bug will be discussed. If you are allergic to these types of bugs, turn back now. Neither I nor me am responsible for any injuries caused by reactions to this post.

I was looking through the [Chemistry meta](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com), and noticed this in the sidebar:

[image]

Pretty self-explanatory. Very, very minor, but quite annoying once you notice it.

Comment: *[obligatory comment about the giant S]*

Comment: `1 hours ago` is a dup, but maybe not in this exact context

Comment: @psubsee2003 [Sklivvz seems not to think so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/204079/revisions)

Comment: Hand-drawn shapes are nice and all, but I think you lost the plot.

Comment: Did you mean to use that link @Undo..? You're missing an `s` :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Oh dear, yes. And I can't edit it now :(

Comment: Hour(s) people hour(s)! We don't need any conditional code just the usual english language convention

Comment: Really need to state it, despite not being Jeff: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: Jeff Atwood knocking in 3. 2. 1. BOOM(s)

Comment: Fixed that for you, @Undo

Comment: The stack exchange software is breaking bad!